# Play a video from a server without exiting the app - Cocoa Touch, iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, video-streaming

Basically I have 8 thumbnails which are buttons. When each button is tapped, it launches the video which is located on my server. However at the moment, when a thumbnail is tapped, the video launches in safari and exits the app. I want it so the video launches in the app instead of exiting it, so once the user has finished watching the video, they are then returned to the app.

Here is the code I've used.

```
-(IBAction)goAbv1:(id)sender; {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/video.mp4"]];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you are on iOS 3.2+

```
NSString *videoURLString = @"http://MypathtoIphoneCompatibleVideoMp4";
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerView = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerView];
```

`presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` will handle the modalviewcontroller and put it on top of the stack automatically so the video can be played. This should work easily.

Comment: Thanks. I've imported the framework MediaPlayer, added the import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> to the header file. But it gives me this error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o`

Comment: Did you set the deployment target for more than ios3.2?

Comment: Are you sure you linked the framework correctly? Go to the project navigator and to the linked frameworks panel. Recheck it is there. If it still throws the error reboot Xcode and retry.

Comment: Yeah. I created a brand new project to see if the code works and it did without any errors. But within my existing project is fails to build without giving the errors which I showed you. http://i.imgur.com/IwZBs.png

Comment: Check on the build files of the project the .m's. I have to go will check later. In any case this answers your question, there are plenty of resources to solve your undefined symbol reference error. If nothing works simply remake the whole project. I assure you it won't be the first time you are forced to do something like that.

Comment: Jeez, I'll have to re make the whole project. Xcode can be so annoying at times. Cheers for the help mate, solved it. :-)